# Need Sample Grails Maven Projects

Tags: maven, grails, jenkins, hudson

I am doing some project on Grails. Till now, I am using IVY to build/run. Now i plan to move to maven build for my Grails.
I keep searching and reading for projects and materials. But i did not find any thing which can give complete guidelines or sample code.

```
 Please let me know if you know or have any thing.
```

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0):

Try generating sample project with this archetype

https://github.com/grails/grails-maven-archetype

Simple execute this command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.grails \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=grails-maven-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.1.0.RC1 \
    -DgroupId=example -DartifactId=my-app
```